# Adding column item as a link in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, list, sharepoint-2010

How do I add an item in a column as a link in a list in Sharepoint Server 2010?

What is the type of column which is showing link to another document?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sharepoint 2010 grid view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100592/sharepoint-2010-grid-view)

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if i understand you correctly.

You have seen the browse for document link in publishing sites, and you want this functionality in your standard list.

Unfortuately you cannot do this, the standard data types are:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/create-a-site-column-HA010157769.aspx

So you are left with just plain old Hyperlink, which doesn't have the browse for document box.

If you try to create a site column with the datatype Publishing Hyperlink, and add it to your list, you should get an error message when you try to browse

"Cannot complete action"

Comment: isn't there any workarounds ? plugins that allow this kind of thing ?!

Answer (score 0):

You can add *Calculated Value* column in the list, and specify the formula for the column which will redirect you to the desired location.

Comment: How? You can't output html as part of a calculated column, SharePoint will escape it for you and you then need some javascript magic to unescape it client side.

Comment: Yes Ryan, you are right about that. Mine solution is possible, only if the link is same for all entries in the table.
However, nice workaround can be if the links are stored simply, in a text column that will not be displayed in the default list view. With this approach, if you add a hyperlink in infopath in the form which will take dynamically the value of the above mentioned text field, then I think it is possible to achieve the functionality without adding javascript. However, the link will only be visible in the "Edit item form", and not from the list view...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jQuery by parsing the link from the title with link or edit button. But also, if you want a non client side solution, there is a good article here http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/jennifer/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=70 on how to add a column and using a workflow fill that column with a "quick link" that the user can provide to people wanting to link to there document. It is a general approach that I think you can see could be adapted to various needs.

For a head start on a jQuery solution check out http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomization/thread/ebda8a32-a6cc-49fa-b7e4-81f762b26266/

Answer (score 0):

In order to link document with list item, you can create "Hyperlink with formatting and constraints for publishing" site column and add it to any list.
If you need to browse and upload multiple files per list item, you can use 3rd party add-ons like [Sparqube Document](http://www.sparqube.com/SharePoint-Document-Column/) column.