# Sharepoint 2010 grid view

Tags: sharepoint, view, grid

How do I add a link column to Sharepoint grid view?

Comment: Do you want to add a hyperlink column to your list? Or do you already have one in the list and you want to show it in the grid view? Also, do you mean the Access Data Grid View for data entry, or do you mean an SPGridView programming object model view? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SPMenuField. It serves two purposes - it configures the hyperlink you follow if you click on the item directly and, optionally, links to a dropdown menu

This is a great primer on MSDN blogs about SPGridView

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powlo/archive/2007/02/25/displaying-custom-data-through-sharepoint-lists-using-spgridview-and-spmenufield.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be supported by the [Telerik SPRadGrid](http://sharepoint.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/web-parts/Pages/TelerikSPRadGridWebPart.aspx) (which I trialed for my SharePoint apps not long ago). Using the Publishers SP List as source for the example I linked, you should have the Name column values as hyperlinks. You might give it a spin.